# Execv with argument array

Tags: c, caesar-cipher, execv

I have a simple C program that creates an array of arguments as required by the second argument of `execv()` that executes a program that computes and outputs the Caeser Cipher decoding of the argument. However the file calling `execv()` seems to ignore the call and moves ahead. What should I do?

**The code**

execv-test-arg.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
        char *argv[3];
        argv[0] = "caesar-cipher";
        argv[1] = "SDQGD";
        argv[2] = "\0";
        execv("caesar-cipher",argv);
        printf("Returned from execv call.\n"); // This is what is being printed
        return 0;
}
```

caesar-cipher.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i, j;

   for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
      j=0;
      while (argv[i][j] != '\0') {
         if ((argv[i][j] >= 'A') && (argv[i][j] <= 'Z')) {
            printf ("%c", 'A'+(argv[i][j]-'A'+23)%26); // To be printed
         }
         else if ((argv[i][j] >= 'a') && (argv[i][j] <= 'z')) {
            printf ("%c", 'A'+(argv[i][j]-'a'+23)%26);
         }
         else if ((argv[i][j] >= '0') && (argv[i][j] <= '9')) {
            printf ("%c", '0'+(argv[i][j]-'0'+7)%10);
         }
         else printf ("Invalid input.\n");
         j++;
      }
      printf(" ");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Required output:

```
PANDA
```

Current output:

```
Returned from execv call.
```

Comment: The calling program does not wait because [these functions do not return to the calling process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/execv-wexecv?view=msvc-170). The system simply returns a value to indicate whether the process was launched. It is not like calling a function or subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start from printing `errno` and seeing what it says.

I suspect the cause is that caesar-cipher is not in the current directory and you aren't specifying the full path. There is `execvp` for taking into account `$PATH`.

Oh, another feature too: you might want to have NULL instead of "\0" as the end of argv.

Comment: *Oh, another feature too: you might want to have NULL instead of "\0" as the end of argv.*  There's no "might" about that one...

Answer (score 1):

From the `man` page:

> *The array of pointers must be terminated by a **null pointer**.*

So, you shouldn't have a pointer pointing at a null terminated string, like this:

```
argv[2] = "\0";
```

It should be:

```
argv[2] = NULL;
```

> seems to ignore the call

It tries to find the `NULL` pointer in your array - but it doesn't know where the array ends - and therefore reads out of bounds with [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) as a result. It may return from `execv` (indicating a failure) but it could also have crashed or done something worse.